# how can i create html tags in asp.net like ul, li, a etc

Tags: asp.net

How can I create HTML tags in asp.net like ul, li, a, etc

In detail and in the simplest way possible with all HTML tags and dynamic manner.

Comment: You need to be more specific with what you want. As the question is asked now the simple answer is to just use those tags in your markup.

Comment: please use the basic html tags, and don't put an ugly runat server there. It's just to display data so get rid of unecessary complexity.
see Moussa answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use HtmlGenericControl. That's exactly what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 11):

If I understand you correctly you can use Repeater control:

```
<ul>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li> <%# Container.DataItem %> </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Then bind this control with your collection of your data:

```
repeater1.DataSource = YourCollectionOfStringHere;
repeater1.DataBind();
```

Hope it will be helpful. If not, sorry for this )

Comment: Some small errors in the code.  <il> should be <ul> and the <ul> inside the ItemTemplate should be <li>.

Comment: yeah thanks! But can anyone tell me how can i use other html controls  dynamically in asp.net like <a> etc because we can't use that anchor tag in asp.net

Comment: i was kinda lost with Container.DataItem i did some looking around and DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImgPath_fr") is what i needed. your answered helped tho

Answer (score 7):

Well, the simplest but not object oriented way to do it:

Add to your .aspx file:

```
<asp:Literal ID="myLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Add to your .aspx.cs file:

```
myLiteral.Text = "<ul><li>apple</li><li>orange</li><li>kiwi</li></ul>";
```

Not nice, but works :)

The easiest object oriented way to do it is with the HtmlGenericControl class. You can create any tag you want with it and at least it assures that these tags are closed properly. Example to create a <div>:

```
string s="This is <strong>a test</strong> of the html HtmlGenericControl class";
HtmlGenericControl ge = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
ge.InnerHtml=s;
this.PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ge);
```

Just keep in mind, that both solutions are working, but neither one is the nice way to get things done. For generating <a> tags you should use HtmlAnchor control, for <div> you should use <asp:Panel> for <span> you should use <asp:Label>, for your list you should use <asp:BulletedList> or the repeater control and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works for displaying. But how to capture the changes done by user to data in `li` tags using this method?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a ul / li set using the BulletedList control:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.aspx

It also has a DisplayMode which you can use to make it display hyperlinks:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.displaymode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create them just like normal html:

example:

```
<ul type="disc">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li> </ul>
```

if you want to tranform them to server side controls you can just add runat="server"